# Reading Zero For Value of all Places in Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm making a game in Java with Swing. I'm using a 2D Array to store my world. I have a text command system and when it calls a variable from the array it returns 0 in every position except for 0,0. Here is my code:

Class for Generating the array:

```
package finalproject;

public class WorldGen {

public int length = 20;
public int width = 20;
public double[][] world = new double[length][width];

public WorldGen(int seed) {

    worldBase(seed);

}

public void worldBase(int seed) {

    if(seed == 1) {

        world[0][0] = 1;

    } else if (seed == 2) {

        world[0][0] = 2;

    } else if (seed == 3) {

        world[0][0] = 3;

    } else if (seed == 4) {

        world[0][0] = 4;

    } else if (seed == 5) {

        world[0][0] = 5;

    } else if (seed == 0) {

        world[0][0] = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));

    }

    worldSmooth(0, 0);

}


public void worldSmooth(int posX, int posY) {

    double tempChunkType;

    for(int x = 1; x < length; x ++) {

        for(int y = 1; y < width; y ++) {

            if(world[posX][posY] == 1) {

                tempChunkType = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
                if(tempChunkType == 1 || tempChunkType == 2 || tempChunkType == 3 || tempChunkType == 4 || tempChunkType == 5) {

                    world[x][y] = 1;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 6 || tempChunkType == 7 || tempChunkType == 8) {

                    world[x][y] = 2;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 9) {

                    world[x][y] = 3;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 10) {

                    world[x][y] = 4;

                }

            } else if(world[posX][posY] == 2) {

                tempChunkType = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
                if(tempChunkType == 1 || tempChunkType == 2 || tempChunkType == 3 || tempChunkType == 4 || tempChunkType == 5) {

                    world[x][y] = 2;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 6 || tempChunkType == 7 || tempChunkType == 8) {

                    world[x][y] = 1;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 9) {

                    world[x][y] = 3;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 10) {

                    world[x][y] = 4;

                }

            } else if(world[posX][posY] == 3) {

                tempChunkType = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
                if(tempChunkType == 1 || tempChunkType == 2 || tempChunkType == 3 || tempChunkType == 4 || tempChunkType == 5) {

                    world[x][y] = 3;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 6 || tempChunkType == 7 || tempChunkType == 8) {

                    world[x][y] = 2;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 9) {

                    world[x][y] = 1;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 10) {

                    world[x][y] = 4;

                }

            } else if(world[posX][posY] == 4) {

                tempChunkType = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
                if(tempChunkType == 1 || tempChunkType == 2 || tempChunkType == 3 || tempChunkType == 4 || tempChunkType == 5) {

                    world[x][y] = 4;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 6 || tempChunkType == 7 || tempChunkType == 8) {

                    world[x][y] = 3;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 9) {

                    world[x][y] = 5;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 10) {

                    world[x][y] = 2;

                }

            } else if(world[posX][posY] == 5) {

                tempChunkType = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
                if(tempChunkType == 1 || tempChunkType == 2 || tempChunkType == 3 || tempChunkType == 4 || tempChunkType == 5) {

                    world[x][y] = 5;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 6 || tempChunkType == 7 || tempChunkType == 8) {

                    world[x][y] = 4;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 9) {

                    world[x][y] = 3;

                } else if(tempChunkType == 10) {

                    world[x][y] = 2;

                }

            }

            posX = x;
            posY = y;

        }

    }


}

}
```

Class for the commands:

```
package finalproject;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ControlPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public String chunkType;
public WorldDisp world = new WorldDisp();
public double[][] worldOb = new double[world.world.length][world.world.width];
public double[][] heightOb = new double[world.world.length][world.world.width];
public int posX = 0;
public int posY = 0;
public int columns = 20;
public int rows = 5;
public JTextField textField = new JTextField(columns);
public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(rows, columns);
public JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
public String newline = "\n";
public String input;

public ControlPanel() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    textField.addActionListener(this);

    setOb();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    textArea.setText(null);

    input = textField.getText();

    textArea.append(textField.getText());
    textField.selectAll();

    commandCheck(input);



}

public void displayPosAndChunk(int posX, int posY, String chunkType) {

    textArea.setText(null);

    textArea.append("X: " + posX + " Y: " + posY + newline);
    System.out.println("You are in a " + chunkType);
    textArea.append("You are in a " + chunkType);

}

public void commandCheck(String input) {

    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {

        posX ++;
        System.out.println("Go right");

    } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {

        posX --;
        System.out.println("Go left");

    } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {

        posY ++;
        System.out.println("Go down");

    } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {

        posY --;
        System.out.println("Go up");

    } else {

        //Send text to textArea in ControlPanel

    }

    System.out.println("At call for displayPosAndChunk. Before this is all fine. X: " + posX + " Y: " + posY);

    System.out.println(worldOb[posX][posY]);

    displayPosAndChunk(posX, posY, chunkIntToString(worldOb[posX][posY]));

}

public String chunkIntToString(double chunkTypeInt) {

    System.out.println(chunkTypeInt);

    if(chunkTypeInt == 1) {

        chunkType = "desert";

    } else if(chunkTypeInt == 2) {

        chunkType = "plains";

    } else if(chunkTypeInt == 3) {

        chunkType = "lightForest";

    } else if(chunkTypeInt == 4) {

        chunkType = "darkForest";

    } else if(chunkTypeInt == 5) {

        chunkType = "pineForest";

    } else {

        chunkType = "nothing. Something is wrong.";

    }

    System.out.println(chunkType);

    return chunkType;

}

public void setOb() {

    worldOb = world.world.world;

}

}
```

What's wrong with my code? I've tried changing how I'm calling the array. One more note, I know the array is generating properly because I have a class (WorldDisp) that generates an array using WorldGen and displays it perfectly. So, what's happening to it?

Comment: Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: _You_ tell us what's wrong. If there's an unhandled exception, post the stack trace. If it doesn't work, tell us the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

All of those positions start at zero, and then your excessive `if` statements check for just about everything *but* zero.

Answer (score 0):

`WorldGen.worldSmooth(int posX, int posY)` is not assigning chunk types to the first row or first column. You should start the `for` loops at 0 (but ignore 0,0). Since 0 is not a valid chunk type you'll always be in 'something is wrong' space along these edges.

`commandCheck(String input)` is not handling the case of going outside the world (for example left or up from the start will move into negative indices). Accessing `worldOb[posX][posY]` could therefore throw an exception which is not being handled. Perhaps you should check whether a move takes you to a valid position and either prevent an invalid move, or wrap around to the other side.

Is there a reason that the world needs to be of type `double`? You could probably represent them as an `int` or `enum`.

Also double check that you're passing in a valid seed. An invalid seed, like -1, would result in an array of 0.0s.

Otherwise since you've confirmed the array is being generated correctly, it's possible that somewhere else in your code you're accessing a different instance.